# Sound not working?

Tags: windows-7, windows, drivers, audio

I have an advent 7109B laptop running Windows 7 Professional 32bit.

Trouble is, sound isn't working! I've tried everything to get it working but still nothing.

I think its a driver issue as Windows can't find any problems itself.

Does anyone know if there is a driver for this old laptop for Windows 7?

Comment: Did you check Device Manager? Are there any unrecognised devices (with a yellow exclamation mark next to them)?

Comment: I checked device manager. My device is there and it says its working correctly. I even managed to update it and still no sound.